# What is the proper elven name for Wood and Wild Elves?

Tags: forgotten-realms, lore, languages

In the Sword Coast Adventure Guide, both the Wood and Wild elves are said to go by the elvish name of "Sy'Tel'Quessir"  (Page 106)

Do they both have the same name? Are Wood elves considered by other elves to have "*abandoned or lost much of their ancient culture*"  due to their flexibility?

Answer (score 9):

This appears to be a typo.  According to the [Forgotten Realms wiki](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Wild_elf),  Wild elves go by the name "Sy'Tel'Quessir", meaning "[People of the Wilds"](http://www.candlekeep.com/library/articles/diction_elf.htm#S), and Wood elves go by the name "Or'Tel'Quessir", meaning "[People of the Wood](http://www.candlekeep.com/library/articles/diction_elf.htm#O)".

Comment: ±0 - This would probably be better if it quoted the specific sources referenced on the wiki, rather than citing the wiki, which could have errors of its own.